# Can I Specify the Session for Multiple Active Result Sets?

Tags: sql-server

I have never used Multiple Active Result Sets before, but it sounds like it will help me solve a problem by allowing multiple connections to share a context.  My question is whether there is a way to specify which connections share context.  According to the documentation, sp_getbindtoken, which was the older version of this technology, you could specify a token to identify each session, and determine which connections shared each session.  I do not see a way to specify which connections share which sessions with MARS.

It sounds like there is just one shared context and your connection can either be a part of it by specifying MARS=true, or not be a part of it.  I would like to have 3 different sessions and determine programmatically which connections share context with each other.  Is that possible?

**Update:**
I want to provide a little more background on my issue to find out if my theory on MARS will even help.

My system is performing well, with the exception of one update query.  I am getting a lot of deadlock errors thrown from this one query.  Based on what I have read about sp_getbindtoken, this older feature could be used to force multiple clients into a single pipeline, so that queries happened serially, which would prevent two queries from deadlocking each other.  MARS is the replacement for sp_getbindtoken, so I was hoping that it would support the same functionality.  I wanted to use MARS only when performing this update query, and let the rest of my system continue to use a connection string that does not use MARS.  Further, if I could specify a context for the MARS queries, it would allow me to split up the update queries along a partition on the table being updated.  I have never used sp_getbindtoken or MARS before, so maybe all of my assumptions about those technologies are wrong, but if I am reading the documentation correctly, it would go a long way to solving my deadlock issue.

Answer (score 2):

"allowing multiple connections to share a context"

No, you're wrong. MARS allows you to retrieve multiple resultsets in a single connection, like:

See this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1a7f4f(v=vs.110).aspx

What you want is not a supported scenario.